# Объясните примерно, как реализовать сохранение ввода в input после прерывания заполнения формы?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

Пользователь заполняет форму, еще не отправил, и закрыл вкладку. Как сохранить его ввод, чтоб он мог продолжить заполнение с того, на чем остановился? 
Использую Laravel. Интересует вообще как это реализовать, ведь чтоб записать в сессию/куки - он должен по крайней мере отправить форму? Использовать аякс после каждого ввода в инпут?

Comment: Вы всё верно поняли. Например, на событие потери фокуса в поле ввода писать в куки

Comment: Используйте localstorage

Answer (score 1):

Пишите html в localstorage и при повторном входе на страницу чекайте есть ли данные, если да - тяните оттуда и размещайте на странице

Подробнее об localstorage - https://learn.javascript.ru/localstorage

Comment: Действительно неплохо, так же поможет, если например сервер упал или пропал интернет у клиента и он решил страницу обновить (многие так делают, думают, что зависла форма).

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле сессия тут не сильно поможет(если конечно это не форма обратной связи или еще какой либо глобальный объект редактирования), данные должны сохраняться не просто как кусок данных, а как черновик конкретной сущности (например черновик формы заполнения профиля пользователя)

Как это сделано в одном из проектов:

Была большая форма редактирования определенного объекта. При каждой потери фокуса определялось, если данные были изменены сущность взводилась в режим редактирования - на сервер отправлялась команда создания черновика с UUID черновика, и следующей командой отправлялась информация о произошедшем изменении в рамках нового черновика.

На стороне сервера для этого функционала(и только для этого) применялась CQRS/ES обрабатывалась команда создания - по сути создавался объект черновика и далее через ES складировались и обрабатывались обновления каждого поля(в том числе не только текстовые поля, но и прочие действия пользователя модифицирующие данные в форме).

А еще было куча логики чтобы черновик мог редактировать только один человек, перехват черновика и прочих радостей конкурентной среды.